# Backslash issue (url in url)

Tags: r

I have seen the solution to this problem in other languages but not in R.
I have a simple api call where I make a url that contains other url.
Something like that:

```
paste0('http://www.server.com/select?q="',url,'"&sort=likes+desc')
```

The issue is when I paste the url which is

```
url = "http://www.someotherserver.com/something/pic.jpg"
```

When I print url it gives me:

```
"http://www.server.com/select?q=\"http://www.someotherserver.com/something/pic.jpg\"&sort=likes+desc"
```

Tried doing gsub, substring, saving to a file but nothing seems to work. How to get rid of these backslashes after q= and after url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code. It produces the string

```
http://www.server.com/select?q="http://www.someotherserver.com/something/pic.jpg"&sort=likes+desc
```

The backslash is inserted only by the `print` function to show you that the `"` does not end the string, but is part of the string.

Compare

```
> "abc"
[1] "abc"
> "abc \"def\""
[1] "abc \"def\""
> cat("abc \"def\"\n")
abc "def"
```

In the second case, it prints a string representation of the string the same you typed in it. However, this is not the actual string that will. You can see the "raw" string by using `cat()`.

Also, the strings `'abd "def"'` and `"abc \"def\""` are equal. These are both different ways to enter the same string. When using single quotes, you do not have to escape double quotes. However, when printing a string, `R` always uses double quotes:

```
> "abc \"def\""
[1] "abc \"def\""
> 'abc "def"'
[1] "abc \"def\""
```